# How do you put data from a txt file into a Grid?

Tags: python, file, grid

I am trying to use a .txt file that is formatted to look like a matrix into a python Grid.

Here is the class I am using to create a Grid:

```
class Grid(object):
"""Represents a two-dimensional array."""

    def __init__(self, rows, columns, fillValue = None):
        self._data = Array(rows)
        for row in xrange(rows):
            self._data[row] = Array(columns, fillValue)

    def getHeight(self):
        """Returns the number of rows."""
        return len(self._data)

    def getWidth(self):
        "Returns the number of columns."""
        return len(self._data[0])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Supports two-dimensional indexing with [][]."""
        return self._data[index]

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the grid."""
        result = ""
        for row in xrange(self.getHeight()):
            for col in xrange(self.getWidth()):
                result += str(self._data[row][col]) + " "
            result += "\n"
        return result
```

It uses another class called Array to build upon a 1D array and make it into a 2D array.
The Code:`Grid(10, 10, 1)` would return a 2D Array with 10 rows and 10 columns with every number in the grid being 1.

**Here is the Array class**

```
class Array(object):
"""Represents an array."""

def __init__(self, capacity, fillValue = None):
    """Capacity is the static size of the array.
    fillValue is placed at each position."""
    self._items = list()
    for count in xrange(capacity):
        self._items.append(fillValue)

def __len__(self):
    """-> The capacity of the array."""
    return len(self._items)

def __str__(self):
    """-> The string representation of the array."""
    return str(self._items)

def __iter__(self):
    """Supports traversal with a for loop."""
    return iter(self._items)

def __getitem__(self, index):
    """Subscript operator for access at index."""
    return self._items[index]

def __setitem__(self, index, newItem):
    """Subscript operator for replacement at index."""
    self._items[index] = newItem
```

I want that 1 to be values from a text file I have which looks like this:

```
9 9
1 3 2 4 5 2 1 0 1
0 7 3 4 2 1 1 1 1 
-2 2 4 4 3 -2 2 2 1
3 3 3 3 1 1 0 0 0
4 2 -3 4 2 2 1 0 0
5 -2 0 0 1 0 3 0 1
6 -2 2 1 2 1 0 0 1
7 9 2 2 -2 1 0 3 2
8 -3 2 1 1 1 1 1 -2
```

The 9,9 represents the rows and columns of the matrix. The only place I can use a list is in the method `readline().split()` which turns the first line into a list.

of course I have the lines;

```
m = open("matrix.txt", "r")
data = m.read
```

where data returns the numbers in string representation as they are formatted from the folder, but i need some way to return each number individually and set it to cells in the Grid. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** My Current Code:

```
g = map(int, m.readline().split())
data = m.read()
matrix = Grid(g[0], g[1], 1)
```

g[0] and g[1] are from the list that have the row and column variables. This way, any .txt file that follows the same format will have the first line be the row and column variables.
I'm trying to figure out how the rest of the data can replace the "1" without using a list to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how does this look:

```
with open('matrix.txt') as f:
    grid_data = [i.split() for i in f.readlines()]
```

This will read each array from the file, format it into a list of values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for simplicity ... but I dont think you need the strip ... split should take care of that ...

Comment: Is there another way to do it without lists? That's where my mind defaulted as well, but the prof isn't allowing the use of a list here. Which is what kind of stumped me.

Comment: what do you mean do it without lists? you are using lists currently .. but sure ... lists are just the most natural way to represent it

Comment: Edited my original question. The only way I can see it to  be done is by doing a for loop for lines in data, but that returns spaces and negative signs separate from their numbers...

Comment: Nick, that grid is just a string representation of the data, which is what i have data already set to. It doesn't allow me to call cells from it, (i.e. grid[0][0] pulls up the entire thing and grid[0][1] goes out of range where as it should be 1 and 3

Comment: So it is. Are you allowed to use a dictionary where the values are lists? This would allow you to use the __getitem__ function

Comment: Maybe. There's a set of code I'm trying to work around that i think will help.

   `for r in range(matrix.getHeight()):
      for c in range(matrix.getWidth()):
        matrix[r][c] = whatever`

this will set each cell of the grid to be equal to **whatever** one at a time... i just can't figure out what to set **whatever** to be.

Comment: edited again above, to include a solution that uses a dictionary of {row : array(data)} pairs. It does use lists to read in the data, but that is all.

Comment: Would setting grid = {} be alright for just making an empty dictionary? Also, what is your array class? I'm getting an error trying to combine your code with my Array class. my Array requires a capactiy (i.e. Array(10) would set an array with 10 spaces, Array(10, 1) would fill each 10 spaces with a 1 value)

Comment: added a new answer - it uses the Grid class to assign values to the matrix - and looking at it now, this is probably what was intended all along? What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
a_width = 9
a_height = 9
data_file = "matrix.dat"

a = numpy.array(open(data_file).read().split(),dtype=int).reshape((a_width,a_height))
#or another alternative below
a = numpy.fromfile("matrix.dat",dtype=int,sep=" ").reshape(9,9)

print a
```

a different solution

```
with open(data_file) as f:
    a = map(str.split,f)

print a
```

which is just a slightly more terse version of Nick Burns Code

Answer (score 0):

A SUPER SIMPLE answer (added a new answer, because it is so much simpler that the previuos)

```
# create a grip object
new_matrix = Grid(9, 9)

with open('matrix.txt') as f:
    # loop through the data
    for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        line = line.split()

        # populate the new_matrix
        for j, value in enumerate(line):
            new_matrix[i][j] = value
```

I like that this uses the Grid class to populate the matrix. With the exception of reading in the data from the file, there is no usage of lists.

Got there (I hope, I think!)

Comment: The Class `Append` does not have a function called `append`. You would need to pass it like this:  `my_array = Array()` and then, `my_array[i].append()`

Comment: By my class array that I added to the original question, new_matrix[i].append(j) is what is causing the problem. new_matrix[i] is an Array type, and it can't/won't append j to it

Comment: Hey wes - now that we have both classes, it runs quite nicely. Edited above

Comment: you will probably need to allow for the first line `(9, 9)` in `matrix.txt`.

Comment: I don't know Nick, i even took off the readline().split() i had that was taking off the 9, 9. Still get an out of range error. I appreciate all the help you've given me tonight though.

Comment: hi wes - if you're still around, let's move this to google plus and run through the whole problem.